# Jenkins, cobertura plugin on windows, app with minGW32 compiler, what is wrong?

Tags: c++, jenkins, cobertura, mingw32

This is my first post here.
I have following problem. I wanted to have reports about code coverage using Jenkins Cobertura plugin.
The application is written in C++ (MinGW32 compiler) on Windows. To achieve some reports I know, that must compile Application with special compiler mode (for gcc is '-gcov' mode) and launch tests. Does anyone know how is named mode,lik '-gcov' for MinGW32 ?

Comment: Have you read gcc docs? For example here https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.2/gcc/Debugging-Options.html

Comment: Actually, MinGW32 uses GCC compiler.